# Фильтр с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, reactjs, lodash

Имеется поле ввода `input` и массив элементов
Нужно реализовать функцию на JavaScript, с помощью которой можно будет производить поиск в массиве по двум полям `ip` и `consumerSi`, используя при этом регулярное выражение `/(\.|\:|\s+)/g`.

То есть вводим `12345`, то в результат должен попасть объект с `ip` равным `123.45.45.34`, фильтр должен опускать символы, которые есть в шаблоне регулярного выражения.

Можно использовать `lodash`

```
[
  {
    ip: "123.45.45.34",
    consumerSi: "00:00:00:00:00:01:6:111",
  },
  {
    ip: "234.35.32.44"
    consumerSi: "00:00:00:00:00:01:6:222",
  },
]
```

Comment: А для 234.35.32.44 какая исходная строка?

Comment: @becouse не понял вопроса

Comment: @becouse мы можем вводить, например, 12345, 0000, 6222,

Comment: Ну 12345 совпадает с 123.45.45.34. Какую строку нужно ввести чтобы совпало со вторым ИП

Comment: Просто не очевиден критерий сравнения двух строк

Comment: @becouse 23435, можно 3244, 3532
по сути изначально это у меня был абсолютно обычный фильтр, который ищет через indexOf(search) !== -1

Comment: @becouse ладно, помоги хотя бы с тем, что бы сделать фильтр по одному полю, например, по полю ip, но с регуляркой)

Comment: Аааа. Введенная строка должна быть подстрокой ип без символовов. Теперь понятно.

Comment: @becouse даа)
то есть до этого вопроса была абсолютно обычный фильтр, сейчас надо с регулярным выражением сделать 
раз понял в чем дело, то попробуй помочь сделать фильтрацию с двумя полями, пожалуйста хд

Comment: Не знаю JS, но возможно есть функция на подобии regexp_match и можно выбирать ей подходящие под шаблон `(?=(.*\.[0-9]){3})([$text]{1,3}\.?){4}$`условия. Пример работы https://regex101.com/r/RDLNe6/1

Answer (score 1):

Одним регулярным выражением не получится сопоставить две строки с игнорированием символов.
Единственная возможность - это избавиться от игнорируемых символов, а затем сопоставить их друг с другом.

Насколько я понял вы имеете в виду такой вариант:

```
var arr=[
  {
    ip: "123.45.45.34",
    consumerSi: "00:00:00:00:00:01:6:111",
  },
  {
    ip: "234.35.32.44",
    consumerSi: "00:00:00:00:00:01:6:222",
  },
]

var re1 = /[\.\:\s]/g;
var re2 = /12345/;
var re3 = /161/;  

for (i=0; i<arr.length;i++){

  if (arr[i]['ip'].replace(re1,'').match(re2) &&
     arr[i]['consumerSi'].replace(re1,'').match(re3)){
    console.log(arr[i])
  }

}
```

Возможная альтернатива для двух строк построить регулярное выражение, где каждый символ сравниваемой строки окружен разделителями.

```
s1="123.45.45.34";
s2="12345";

res="[\\.\\:\\s]*";

for (i=0; i<s2.length;i++){
  res=res+s2[i]+"[\\.\\:\\s]*";
}

re=new RegExp(res,"g");

console.log(s1.match(re));
```